# how to add multiple apps using pwa (add to home screen)

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I want to add or download multiple apps using pwa (add to home screen) eg: using www.example.com/value1 am able to add my app but while using www.example.com/value2 am not able to add my app how can I add multiple apps using pwa

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You just need to use different Web App Manifest files for all the different "pages" or "sites" you wish to have available for adding to homescreen.

For www.example.com/value1 you'll have /manifest-value1.json and for www.example.com/value2 you'll have /manifest-value2.json. Each page has its own HTML meta tag for its corresponding manifest file.

In the manifest files you use different start_url values.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest